# WPF - DocumentViewer not allowing page up/down

Tags: wpf

I have set the Document of a DocumentViewer control and the XPS document has 5 pages. I can only see the first page and I cannot scroll down through the pages using the mouse scroll or the vertical scrollbar. I can however use the page down/up keys to navigate the pages.

Any ideas what I can do to get the full page scrolling functionality working.

[image]

EDIT: if I resize the window to be much smaller, the scroll bar enables, but I can only scroll for a small portion of the page.

Comment: could you create a sample project so that we can test our ideas?

Comment: Good point. I'll get something pulled together.

Comment: can you share the example code what you used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just made a test and the scrollbars work perfectly. The code I used is:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DocumentViewer x:Name="documentViewer"/>
</Grid>
```

Code-Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        XpsDocument document = new XpsDocument("Sample.xps", FileAccess.Read);
        this.documentViewer.Document = document.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
        document.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I do get the same experience with this simple example...I'm trying to extract the relevant code from my full (not working) solution to try and replicate the issue and find where it differs from this

Comment: sorry for the delay, but I actually found out that it was a problem in a style provided by a third party which has now been resolved. I have accepted this solution because the simple working sample made me realise that there must be something else wrong as the framework code was fine.

Comment: Hi, my coding same as your marked answer, but don't have idea which code triggering the scrollbar works...can you advise pls? I still not manage to get it works.